# get values from the current table

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have table with Doctrine:

```
Name:
  columns:
    name_id: { type: integer(11),  primary: true,  autoincrement: true }
    name_name: { type: string(65)}
    parent_name_id: { type: integer(11) }
```

If i edit Name i would like in input parent_name_id list select with name_id, added previous. 
I would like use:

NameTable.class.php:

```
  static public $name = array(
    'full-time' => 'Full time', //  foreach ???
    'part-time' => 'Part time', // ????
    'freelance' => 'Freelance'  // ????
  );

  public function getName()
  {
    return self::$name;
  }
```

and

```
$this->widgetSchema['parent_name_id'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
  'choices'  => Doctrine::getTable('Name')->getName(),
  'expanded' => true,
));
```

but how can i generated this in model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Name:
  columns:
    name_id: { type: integer(11),  primary: true,  autoincrement: true }
    name_name: { type: string(65)}
    parent_name_id: { type: integer(11) }
```

1. Why   name_name ? It will be good, rename it for  name :)
   Than you make:

**$ php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load --no-confirmation**

and in **/lib/model/doctrine/base** in **BaseName.class.php** you can see all generated method, for example

```
* @method string              getName()                Returns the current record's "name" value
```

You can use [**sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice**](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice)

For example:

```
$this->widgetSchema['parent_name_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice('model' => 'Name', 'add_empty' => false, 'multiple' => false);
```